# Azure web role trouble accessing external web service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, azure

I have an Azure web role that accesses an external WCF based SOAP web service (port 80) for various bits of data.  The response from this service is highly erratic.  I routinely get the following error.

> There was no endpoint listening at 
>   http://www.myexternalservice.com/service.svc that could accept the message. This is 
>   often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.

To isolate the problem I created a simple console app to repetitively call this service in 1 second intervals and log all responses.

```
    using (var svc = new MyExternalService())
    {
        stopwatch.Start();
        var response = svc.CallService();
        stopwatch.Stop();
        Log(response, stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);    
    }
```

If I RDP to one of my Azure web instances and run this app it takes 10 to 20 attempts before it gets a valid response from the external service.  These first attempts are always accompanied by the above error.  After this "warm up period" it runs fine.  If I stop the app and then immediately restart, it has to go back through the same "warm up" period.

**However**, if I run this same app from any other machine I receive valid responses immediately.  I have run this logger app on servers running in multiple data centers (non Azure), desktops on different networks, etc...  These test runs are always very stable.

I am not sure why this service would react this way in the Azure environment.  Unfortunately, for the short term I am forced to call this service but my users cannot tolerate this inconsistency.

A capture of network traffic on the Azure server indicates a large number of **SynReTransmit**'s in 10 second intervals during the same time I experience the connection errors.  Once the "warm up" is complete the SynReTransmit's no longer occur.

Comment: Can you get a network trace to see what you are getting back?

Comment: I am installing WireShark now actually.

Comment: It appears the requests are never making it to the web service servers.  Network traffic captures indicate multiple SynReTransmit's without associated responses.

Comment: What if you log into the Azure machine and just try and hit the public page of the service, does that work immediately, or is there a delay?

Comment: The response from the browser is immediate if I hit the WSDL or service main page.

Comment: I am wondering if it's a firewall issue and it's taking some time before it sees your host as valid for out bound traffic.

Comment: In fact does the issue go away after awhile or doe sit keep coming back

Comment: Zonder, it comes back every time I start a new instance of my test console app.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We found a *solution* for this problem although I am not completely happy with it.  After exhausting all other courses of action we changed the load balancer to **Layer-7 Load Balancing** from **Layer-4 Load Balancing**.  While this fixed the problem of lost requests I am not sure why this made a difference.

Comment: You changed load balancing on the external service or on Azure?

Answer (score -1):

The Windows Azure data center region where the Windows Azure application is deployed might not be near the external Web Service. The local machine you're trying (which works fine) might be close to the web service. That’s why there might be huge latency in Azure which would likely cause it to fail.

Success accessing WSDL from a browser in Azure VM might be due to browser caching. Making a function call from browser would tell you if it is actually making a connection.

Comment: The web service data center is actually within a couple miles of the azure data center.  Also, I have RDP'd to the Azure server and tested latency and it is very very low.  I am not browsing from a browser...the calls are coming from a console app.